# How to modify timestamp field format in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField('User', null=True, blank=True, related_name='liked_posts')
    savers = models.ManyToManyField('User', null=True, blank=True, related_name='saved_posts')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to return the timestamp field in json as: `timestamp.strftime('%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p')`
I've been suggested to write this code in the model's serializer:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    str_timestamp = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name="get_str_timestamp"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_str_timestamp(self, obj: Post):
        return obj.timestamp.strftime('%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p')
```

But it doesn't work and it still has its raw format.

Comment: Replace `str_timestamp = ...` with `timestamp = ...`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield

For your case:
str_timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p")

Or if you need to customize all datetime fields. Configure REST_FRAMEWORK -> DATETIME_FORMAT